# C++ A* algorithm not always having the target node in path

Tags: c++, a-star

I implemented an A* algorithm in C++ but the vector doesn't always have the target node in it resulting in an endless loop. The library I'm using is: https://nullptr.club/libkmint/index.html. The function shortestPathToDist() should do the following: find the shortest path from the source node to the target node using A* ad return that path. Is this a correct implementation of A* or did I do something wrong and what?

Helper.hpp:

```
#ifndef UFO_HELPER_HPP
#define UFO_HELPER_HPP

#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include "kmint/map/map.hpp"

namespace kmint {
    namespace ufo {
        class helper {
            public:
                helper();

                std::vector<const map::map_node*> shortestPathToDist(const kmint::map::map_node& source_node, const kmint::map::map_node& target_node);
            private:
                const map::map_node* helper::smallestDistance(std::map<const map::map_node*, float>& actualCost, std::map<const map::map_node*, float>& heuristicCost, std::vector<const kmint::map::map_node*>& queue);
                float heuristic(const map::map_node& source_node, const map::map_node& target_node);
            };
    }
}

#endif
```

Helper.cpp:

```
#include "kmint/ufo/helper.hpp"

namespace kmint {
    namespace ufo {
        helper::helper() {

        }

        std::vector<const map::map_node*> helper::shortestPathToDist(const map::map_node& source_node, const map::map_node& target_node)
        {
            std::vector<const map::map_node*> path;
            std::vector<const map::map_node*> visited;
            std::vector<const map::map_node*> queue;
            std::map<const map::map_node*, const map::map_node*> previous;
            std::map<const map::map_node*, float> cost;
            std::map<const map::map_node*, float> heuristic_cost;

            queue.push_back(&source_node);
            cost[&source_node] = 0;
            heuristic_cost[&source_node] = heuristic(source_node, target_node);

            while (queue.size() > 0) {
                const map::map_node* shortest_path_node = smallestDistance(cost, heuristic_cost, queue);

                for (int i = 0; i < shortest_path_node->num_edges(); i++) {
                    map::map_edge edge = (*shortest_path_node)[i];
                    const map::map_node *node_to = &edge.to();

                    if (std::find(visited.begin(), visited.end(), node_to) == visited.end()
                        && std::find(queue.begin(), queue.end(), node_to) == queue.end()) {
                        queue.push_back(node_to);
                    }

                    if (cost.find(node_to) == cost.end() || cost[node_to] > cost[shortest_path_node] + edge.weight())
                    {
                        cost[node_to] = cost[shortest_path_node] + edge.weight();
                        heuristic_cost[node_to] = heuristic(*shortest_path_node, target_node);
                        previous[node_to] = shortest_path_node;
                    }

                    if (node_to->node_id() == target_node.node_id())
                    {
                        cost[node_to] = cost[shortest_path_node] + edge.weight();
                        heuristic_cost[node_to] = heuristic(*shortest_path_node, target_node);
                        previous[node_to] = shortest_path_node;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                queue.erase(queue.begin());
                visited.push_back(shortest_path_node);
            }

            // shortest path to target_node
            const map::map_node* current_node = nullptr;

            for (auto const&[key, val] : previous) {
                if (key != nullptr && key != NULL) {
                    if (key->node_id() == target_node.node_id()) {
                        current_node = val;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            path.clear();

            if (current_node == nullptr || current_node == NULL) {
                std::cout << "could not find target node\n";
                //this->shortest_path_to_target(source_node, target_node);
                return path;
            }

            while (current_node != &source_node) {
                if (current_node != nullptr && current_node != NULL) {
                    if (path.size() > 0) {
                        bool found = false;
                        for (auto &p : path) {
                            if (p != NULL && p != nullptr && p->node_id() == current_node->node_id()) {
                                found = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (!found) {
                            path.insert(path.begin(), current_node);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        path.insert(path.begin(), current_node);
                    }
                }

                for (auto const&[key, val] : previous) {
                    if (key != nullptr && key != NULL && current_node != nullptr && current_node != NULL) {
                        if (key->node_id() == current_node->node_id()) {
                            current_node = val;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return path;
        }
        // manhatan heuristic
        float helper::heuristic(const map::map_node& fNode, const map::map_node& sNode)
        {
            return std::abs(fNode.location().x() - sNode.location().x()) + std::abs(fNode.location().y() - sNode.location().y());
        }

        const map::map_node* helper::smallestDistance(std::map<const map::map_node*, float>& actualCost, std::map<const map::map_node*, float>& heuristicCost, std::vector<const map::map_node*>& queue)
        {
            const map::map_node* sDN = nullptr;
            for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++)
            {
                if (sDN == nullptr || actualCost[queue[i]] + heuristicCost[queue[i]] < actualCost[sDN] + heuristicCost[sDN]) {
                    sDN = queue[i];
                }
            }

            return sDN;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ```std::vector<const map::map_node*> visited;``` Why are you using ```vector``` to indicate visited nodes instead of a ```set```?

Comment: @Melon I don't have a particular reason for that, are you suggesting using a set might solve issues?

Comment: Certainly not. But if you have really big map, ```vector``` will be too slow. ```set``` and ```unordered_set``` are faster in regards to searching for elements.

As for your problem, do you have a small enough data that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Melon as in the source code from the map? I'm not totally sure what data you want

Comment: how do you test your code to make sure it works?

Comment: @Melon this is just 1 class from my project, not runnable by itself

Comment: ```vector doesn't always have the target node in it resulting in an endless loop``` is what you stated in your question. So you clearly provided (or something/somebody) provided some data to your program. What is that data?

Comment: I can send you the complete project via wetransfer or a github repo if you want because I got no idea how you would like to receive 'data'.

Answer (score 2):

`queue.erase(queue.begin());`. This is a bug. You are erasing the oldest added object, while you should pop the current shortest path node.

You should also remove the shortest path node from the visited set!

**The real issue is that you are not using the correct data structures.**

```
std::vector<const map::map_node*> queue;
```

should become

```
using scored_node = std::pair<double, const map::map_node*>
std::priority_queue<scored_node, std::vector<scored_node>, std::greater<scored_node>> queue;
```

With this change, you don't need `smallestDistance` anymore, and you should use

```
const auto shortest_path_scored_node = queue.top();
const auto shortest_path_node = shortest_path_scored_node.second;
queue.pop();
visited.erase(shortest_path_node);
```

Rather than use a vector

```
std::vector<const map::map_node*> visited;
```

you should use an unordered set, given you just care whether the element was visited. You are guaranteed uniqueness and fast retrieval without effort.

```
std::unodered_set<const map::map_node*> visited;
```

Comment: I changed the function to this: https://pastebin.com/iKEuhVvL. I'm pretty sure that I did something wrong because it only loops over the edges of the source node and stops after that

Comment: the first score should be infinite, not zero